# Issue with Q.all where it won't wait for all promises to complete

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I have put up a small example of my use case, see below (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BWNba/165/):

Basically Q.all would only work correctly when the biggest job is processed first. Is there anything I am doing here to get this to work correctly ?

```
function findPersonWithId(id) {
    var deffered = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(function(){
    var newPerson = {id: 123}
    deffered.resolve(newPerson)
  },300)


  return deffered.promise;
}

function loadHobbies(person) {
    var deffered = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(function(){
    person.hobbies = ['programming', 'surfing', 'cooking']  
    deffered.resolve(person)
  },100)

  return deffered.promise;
}

function loadAddress(person) {
    var deffered = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(function(){
    person.address = 'Melbourne, Australia'
    deffered.resolve(person)
  },200)

  return deffered.promise;
}

function loadPersonalDetails(person) {
    var deffered = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(function(){
    person.name = 'Bob'
    person.age = 99
    person.gender = 'male'
    deffered.resolve(person)
  },300)

  return deffered.promise;
}

function loadRand(person) {
    var deffered = Q.defer();

  var rand = ~~(Math.random() * 1000)
  setTimeout(function(){
    person[rand] = rand
    deffered.resolve(person)
  },rand)

  return deffered.promise;
}

function getPersonChain() {
  return findPersonWithId(123)
  .then(loadHobbies)
  .then(loadAddress)
  .then(loadPersonalDetails)
}

function getPersonQAllSmFirst() {
  return findPersonWithId(123)
  .then(function(person){
    return Q.all(
    loadHobbies(person),
    loadAddress(person),
    loadPersonalDetails(person)
    )
  })
}

function getPersonQAllLgFirst() {
  return findPersonWithId(123)
  .then(function(person){
    return Q.all(
    loadPersonalDetails(person),
    loadHobbies(person),
    loadAddress(person)
    )
  })
}

getPersonChain()
  .done(function(person){
    $('.person').append(JSON.stringify(person))
  })


getPersonQAllSmFirst()
  .done(function(person){
    $('.person2').append(JSON.stringify(person))
  })

getPersonQAllLgFirst()
  .done(function(person){
    $('.person3').append(JSON.stringify(person))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

`Q.all` accepts an **array of promises** and returns Promise which is resolved if all promises are resolved or rejected if one of them is rejected.

Your calls to `Q.all(promise, promise, promise)` are not valid. It has to be `Q.all([promise, promise, promise])`.

**Returned promise is resolved with an array of results** from promises, in your case it will be 3 same persons.

Little example (will print 1, 2, 3 to console):

```
Q.all([
  Promise.resolve(1), 
  Promise.resolve(2), 
  Promise.resolve(3)
]).then(function(numbers) { console.log(numbers); };
```

To make it work, you need to change your code like this https://jsfiddle.net/g8sgqrof/

Comment: Seems like this works in jsfiddle. But in my node application it won't. Where my calls are sql queries ...

Comment: Then we need to see original code because probably your example is not the right analogy for what you are doing. Are those SQL queries promises?

Comment: Yes, they are promises.

Comment: Please show a part of code with sql queries and what library for sql are you using.